# Android custom component in xml doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have this custom view:

```
package com.myapp;

public class CustomView extends View {

  public CustomView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    CharSequence text = "HELLO";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, text, duration);
    toast.show();
  }
}
```

I wanted to place it by xml, so this is what i wrote in `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <view
    class="com.myapp.CustomView"
    id="@+id/customText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Contents of `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Anyway I can't see the red view when the application is opened, and I cannot see the Toast as well, what am I missing?

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention it, I also tried this way:

```
<com.myapp.CustomView
  id="@+id/inputText"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:background="@color/red"
/>
```

but it doesn't work

---

**UPDATE**

This is the full code:

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  /**
   * Called when the activity is first created.
   */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

CustomView.java:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

  @Override
  public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.d("myapp.contextview","context constructor");
    throw new RuntimeException("Trying to crash the app");
  }

  @Override
  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    Log.d("myapp.contextview","context+attributeset constructor");
    throw new RuntimeException("Trying to crash the app");
  }

  @Override
  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context,attrs,defStyleAttr);
    Log.d("myapp.contextview","context+attributeset+defstyleattr constructor");
    throw new RuntimeException("Trying to crash the app");
  }

}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <com.myapp.CustomView
    id="@+id/customText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Did remember how you fixed this?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you declare it this way.

```
 <com.myapp.CustomView     
  id="@+id/customText"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:background="@color/red"
/>
```

you need also to override the constructor with the `Context` and `AttributeSet`

```
CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I still can't see the red rectangle in my app

Comment: it is strange. Can you try overriding onMeasure and see what it is the real size?

Comment: Tried, no log gets printed

Comment: android is not measuring it, that's why you do see nothing on the screen. Can you try to put a background image instead of the colour ? Just for debugging purpose or assign a fix size to both width and height

Comment: I also tried logging in every overridden constructor and nothing gets logged, so I think the class is not being loaded at all...

Comment: Which debugger? How can I do it?

Comment: eclipse has its own internal debugger. next to the launch icon (the green play icon) you have an icon with a sort of insect. Put a breakpoint in every constructor of your custom view and see where it hit

Comment: But I don't use eclipse :)

Comment: It the same for android studio. Probably change the icon

Comment: I don't use android studio, I'm using netbeans and the debugger just runs the application as the "Run" button does

Comment: Yep I did, and the debug button just starts the application

Comment: do you actually know what a brekpoint is ? It is not meant to start the application but to "break" its flow in order to allow you to analyze objects/variable etc

Comment: I know what a breakpoint is. I'll rephrase the sentence: I set the breakpoints but when I hit the debug button it just runs the applications, the debug console doesn't start and breakpoints are totally ignored.

Comment: I also tried throwing a `RuntimeException` in every constructor of the custom view to see if the application crashes. It does not crash, so the View is not even being created

Comment: The code is the one I posted, could it be that it's not working due to the phone having a custom rom instead of the stock one?

Comment: but are you setting somewhere this layout?

Comment: Yes, I have the `onCreate` method which just has `super.onCreate(savedInstance); setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: and you are telling me that the CustuomView constructrs are not getting called?

Comment: Yes, as I said I've put a `Log.d` for each of the overridden constructors and nothing gets logged while if i put a `Log.d` in the Activity file I can see it in the log

Comment: also you told me that you thrown an exception in every constructor, am I wrong?

Comment: Yep, and the application doesn't crash while it should

Comment: it is strange. Could you update your question with the modifications your brought to your CustomView? Post the Activity as well

Comment: you missed the super call in each constructor. Also put the override annotation. This way if something is wrong you get compile time errors

Comment: then I am clueless. in your activity try to retrieve your customview and check if the its reference is valid, and set its background color programmatically. Still I am curious. As soon as I get home I will give it a try

Comment: I tried `findViewById(R.id.customText)` but it returned `null`

Comment: then you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to alert your view like this :

```
<com.myapp.CustomView 
    android:id="@+id/customText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
  />
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this, I also tried this way and it doesn't work. Anyway, the Android documentation says that both ways should work

Comment: You have to declare attribute in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor, that you write in:

```
public CustomView(Context c) {
    super(c);
```

call are not always, override other constructors and put your logic to new method **init()**.